# Projective Closure of an Affine Variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

If $Y\subseteq\mathbb{A}_n$ is an affine variety, we identify $\mathbb{A}^n$ with an open set $U_0\subseteq\mathbb{P}^n$ by the homeomorphism $\varphi_0\colon U_0\to\mathbb{P}^n$ defined by $\varphi_0([a_0:\dots: a_n])=(a_1,\dots, a_n)$. Then we can speak of $\overline{Y}$, the closure of $Y$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$, which is called the projective closure of $Y$.

> **Question** Could someone explain to me the meaning of this thing? Why can we talk about closure in $\mathbb{P}^n$ only after this identification?

Comment: To talk about a closure in $\mathbb{P^n}$ we first have to think of it as a subset of $\mathbb{P^n}$, right?

Comment: $\phi_0$ is supposed to identify $\mathbb A^n$ with the open set $U_0$, so it should be a homeomorphism $\mathbb A^n\to U_0$ or the inverse of that. So it should map $(a_1,\dots,a_n)\mapsto[1:a_1:\dots:a_n]$ or map $[a_0:a_1:\dots:a_n]\mapsto(a_1/a_0,\dots,a_n/a_0)$.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I understand!